# Are the following definitions of conjugates related?

Tags: group-theory, definition

I have seen the following two definitions of conjugates and I'm wondering if these definitions are related somehow?

In "A Book of Abstract Algebra" by Pinter, the definition is

> Let $G$ be a group (with operation $*$) and $a, x \in G$. then $x * a * x^{-1}$ is called a **conjugate**.

In "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Axler, the definition is

> For the real field, the **conjugate** of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is $x$. For the complex field, the **conjugate** of $(a, b) \in \mathbb{C}$ is $(a, -b)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both cases is is the image under a group action.

In the first case the action of $G$ on itself, the image of $a$ when acting by $x$.

In the second case is the action of the Galois automorphism "complex conjugation" on the complex numbers.

Comment: This is certainly true (+1). But does history support this conclusion?